# Strange VIM behaviour with wrapped lines: When using word movements, visual and actual cursor position diverge

Tags: vim, word-wrap, line-breaks, text-cursor

I did the following:

<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> for change word.
Then, <kbd>esc</kbd> for normal mode.
Then, <kbd>b</kbd> a couple of times.

However, while I expected to jump to the beginning of the words sit, dolor, ipsum, the cursor did not move there. When I inserted text, however, it somehow actually was there.

To sum up, what I wanted to do worked, but the cursor position did not reflect that when pressing <kbd>b</kbd>. Also, the line wrapping looked strange.

What's wrong here?

I recently upgraded from Vim 7.3 to 7.4. The problem does **not** occur in the previous version!

[image: movements]
Here's the part of my `.vimrc` I edited last (the rest has been there for about a year, so I skipped it):

```
set number
set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 noet
set clipboard+=unnamed
set linebreak
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set shell=/bin/sh
set ic
set completeopt=menu,menuone
let g:ycm_auto_trigger=0
let g:tex_flavor="latex"
let g:ycm_key_invoke_completion = ""
inoremap <c-@> <c-x><c-u>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, that has been fixed with [patch 7.4.579](https://github.com/vim/vim/tree/v7.4.579). There have been other similar patches afterwards added, because of some similar problems.